Matrix multiplication interactions with scalar multiplication
In my linear algebra textbook, it states the following theorem:

Using this equation, it then derives the inverse matrix of $T$ (assuming $T$ is invertible):

(in both definitions, the ⋅ represents matrix multiplication)
To improve my understanding, I wanted to try to use the former equation to derive the latter. We can do so in two ways. Either using T ⋅ adj(T) or adj(T) ⋅ T.
I found adj(T) ⋅ T to be easier by using right multiplication of the inverse:
$$adj(T) ⋅ T ⋅ T^{-1} = |T| ⋅ I ⋅ T^{-1}$$
$$adj(T) ⋅ I = |T| ⋅ T^{-1}$$
$$adj(T) = |T| ⋅ T^{-1}$$
$$T^{-1} = (1/|T|) ⋅ adj(T) $$
However, when I tried to derive the formula using T ⋅ adj(T), I ran into a strange situation. In the first iteration, I simply right matrix multiply both sides by the inverse of T. In the second case, I need to left matrix multiply by the inverse of T:
$$T^{-1} ⋅ T ⋅ adj(T) = T^{-1} ⋅ |T| ⋅ I$$
This is where I ran into an issue. Namely, how do I interpret the right hand side? What does it mean to left hand multiply a matrix with a scalar?
$$T^{-1} ⋅ |T| ⋅ I$$
If I change the notation slightly, I can show the right hand side as following:
$$T^{-1}(|T| ⋅ I)$$
This prompts additional questions. First, is matrix multiplication distributive over scalar multiplication? If it is, then the following statement is true:
$$T^{-1}(|T| ⋅ I) = T^{-1}|T| ⋅ T^{-1}I$$
Yet, something about this distribution seems "off". That is, the first term interprets the application of T inverse as scalar multiplication between a matrix and a scalar. However, the second term interprets the application of T inverse as a matrix multiplication between two matrices. I lack the mathematical maturity to articulate why I perceive this as wrong in some way. How can a single operation (left matrix multiply) be perceived as two different operations?

If $a$ is a scalar and $M$ and $N$ are matrices, then $aMN=MaN=MNa$; think of scalar multiplication by $a$ as multiplication by $aI$, which commutes; scalar multiplication distributes over matrix addition $a(M+N)=aM+aN$, but that’s

…a different thing

Does Matrix Multiplication "Distribute" over Scalar Multiplication ? NO
Is it true that $T^{-1}(|T| ⋅ I) = T^{-1}|T| ⋅ T^{-1}I$ ? NO
Consider this :

Matrix Multiplication is "Associative" , that is , $ABC \equiv (AB)C \equiv A(BC)$
Multiplication involving Matrix & Scalar is "Commutative" , that is , $Aa=aA$
Scalar $a$ can be treated like $aI$ where-ever it makes sense , eg Chain Multiplication.
Put that together to get : $aAB=(aA)B=(Aa)B=(AaI)B=A(aI)B=A(aB)=A(Ba)=ABa$

We are using certain Axioms here. We can alternately use the Summation of Matrix Multiplication (involving the Individual Elements) to make that Claim. In that Case , there is only scalar multiplication involved & we can easily move $a$ from Start to Middle to End.
Distributivity :
OP rightly perceives that it is wrong , though OP is unable to articulate it.
Consider $aABCD=aAaBaCaD$ , we will get larger & larger values.
Check $A=AI=AII=AIII=AIIII$ , then $aA=aAaI=aAaIaI=aAaIaIaI=aAaIaIaIaI$ , which is growing without limits
Simple Case : $aII=aIaI$ : we will get Matrix with Diagonal Elements $a^2$ (wrong) , not $a$ (right)
Details :
Check out Theorem 2.2.1 @ https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Fundamentals_of_Matrix_Algebra_(Hartman)/02%3A_Matrix_Arithmetic/2.01%3A_Matrix_Addition_and_Scalar_Multiplication
Check out Discussion @ Matrix and scalar multiplication
